# Is it a security concern to not refresh the page or redirect when logging out of a SPA?

Tags: angular, security, browser, single-page-application

On logout, our single page application clears local storage, etc. Then, it loads a logout component which informs the user that they have been logged out.

However, from time to time, we introduce memory leaks in our application, and in-memory variables stick around longer than they should (we fix these memory leaks when we find them, but we can't always be sure we have removed all of them. We use Angular, so the most common issue is that root-injected services are still alive even when we redirect to the logout page).

Our concern is represented by this scenario:

1. An authenticated/authorized user, A, uses a shared computer to fetch data from our server that they view in the SPA
2. User A logs out of the application, leaving the browser window open
3. Using the still open browser, malicious user, B, uses the browser's devTools to set breakpoints and inspect un-garbage-collected variables that contain data from the server that user A already fetched and that user B is not authorized to view.

Is this scenario a valid security concern, or is it outside the scope of a SPA because another user has physical access to the machine ([chrome considers physical access to be out of scope](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/security/faq.md#Why-arent-physically_local-attacks-in-Chromes-threat-model))?

And if it is a valid concern, is refreshing or redirecting on logout enough to mitigate?

Comment: I think it's not an issue with the SPA, it's the session token that should be invalidated upon logout. Anything left in the SPA after logging out should not be able to get resources from the server.

Comment: If `On logout, our single page application clears local storage, etc.` and token/values are invalidated which values are available to read in point #3? Does user 1 and user 2 use the same credentials? Does the API validate token on each request and ensure logged in user has the necessary permissions?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky, the concern isn't that user B could access the API again (we do indeed invalidate session tokens). The concern is that user B could use the browser's devTools to e.g. set breakpoints and inspect the variables which may still contain some of the data that user A already fetched from the server.